# How to convert bool to int in MySql

Tags: mysql

I'm new to MySql. So I don't know many things like Casting of data types.  How can I convert bool to int in MySql. And also how can I convert decimal to Int in MySql.

Comment: do you want to change datatype of columns ??

Comment: @NAVEED : I want to cast the Bool type to Int

for ex:
                DECLARE bo BOOL;
  SET bo = TRUE;
  SELECT CAST(bo AS INT);

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Typecasting boolean to integer:

```
SELECT CAST(1=1 AS SIGNED INTEGER); /* 1 */
```

Same for decimal and strings:

```
SELECT CAST("1.23" AS SIGNED INTEGER); /* 1 */
```